# powershell and secureString class

Tags: security, powershell, ftp, securestring

Attempting to access an FTP site, I can use a plain text password in credentials and it works fine, but when I use a SecureString it fails to authenticate.  Examples:

```
$pw = "mypw"
$ftp = [system.net.ftpwebrequest] [system.net.webrequest]::create("ftp:myserver")
$ftp.Credentials  = new-object system.net.networkcredential("myuid", $pw)
```

works fine. But the following fails

```
$pw = "mypw"
$ftp = [system.net.ftpwebrequest] [system.net.webrequest]::create("ftp:myserver")
$ss = convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force $pw
$ftp.Credentials  = new-object system.net.networkcredential("myuid", $ss)
```

But that fails to authenticate.  What am I misunderstanding?

(BTW I know that I don't want plaintext pw  in my script.  This is just an example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because FTP cannot handle anything other than plain text username and passwords unless you are using secure FTP. Is there some confusion here?

Comment: You are correct, some confusion. I thought that the SecureString class stored a decrytpable pw.  Of course, that's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is tagged with both "ftp" and "security" I can only recommend to you to never use ftp if you want any security at all. Use ssh instead of telnet, use scp instead of rcp, and **use sftp instead of ftp.** Otherwise it is quite pointless to try to protect the password in memory and then send it in cleartext over the network. I would understand using ftp in the nineties even though I didn't recommend it back then. But now? I see no excuse.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that doesn't explain what's going wrong, so I've downvoted it as a answer.  I have no control over the ftp server.